# Running methods inside a block in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

This is probably a dumb question, but still... I'm calling a function inside a block like this:

```
let makeRocks = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(self.createMyNode),<---- here should be () 
                                   SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1, withRange: 0.15)])

func createMyNode() {
    // blabla
}
```

I don't get it. There should be parentheses after `self.createMyNode` but this still compiles. How is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not in fact calling the function, `createMyNode` will be called inside `SKAction.runBlock`, you're simply passing it as an argument.

Take a look at the type `SKAction.runBlock` accepts, from the [`SKAction` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:):

```
class func runBlock(_ block: dispatch_block_t) -> SKAction
```

And from the [GCD documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@dispatch_block_t):

```
typealias dispatch_block_t = () -> Void
```

Therefore, `SKAction.runBlock` accepts a function (or closure, they're the same thing), which takes no arguments and returns `Void`; which is exactly what you're suppling with `createMyNode`.

With this information it's clear to see why you don't add parentheses after `createMyNode` - because that would call the function, thus passing `Void` (the return type of `createMyNode`) to `SKAction.runBlock`, which `SKAction.runBlock` won't accept.

---

To clarify, here's another example. Say you had the function:

```
func takesAFunc(c: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Void {
    print(c(1, 2))
}
```

And you wanted to pass in a function that added the two numbers. You *could* write:

```
takesAFunc { num1, num2 in
    num1 + num2
}

// Prints: 3
```

But alternatively, you could just pass in the `+` operator that accepts `Int`s - that's a function too. Take a look at the definition:

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
```

That matches the type required by `takesAFunc`, therefore you can write:

```
takesAFunc(+) // Prints: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`runBlock` wants a function as parameter which you provide here (so `self.createMyNode` is only a reference to the function itself).

But you can also wrap the function call in a closure like so:

```
let makeRocks = 

SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock{ self.createMyNode() },
                                   SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1, withRange: 0.15)])
```